# How to order by desc from other table rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I know this question is asked several times, but I have tried all of them but none of them worked for me.

The scenario is I have Program table in which I have different programs. The other table is `EditedProgram` which have multiple entries of Program.

**So, What I need to do is:**

I want to show a single entry of `Program` on the bases of `ProgramID` that is already in `EditedProgram` and sort all these enteries based on `created_at` of `EditedProgram` which are multiple.

**The query is:**

```
Program.where('id in (?)', EditedProgram.order('created_at desc').map(&:program_id).uniq)
```

But it is not ordered as expected

**and:**

```
Program.joins(:edited_programs).order('edited_programs.updated_at desc').group('programs.id')
```

But it shows different entries from `EditedProgram` when it should show only one from `Program` that has edits in `EditedProgram` and then order by `created_at` from `EditedProgram` table.

Comment: What do you mean by "But it shows different entries from EditedProgram"? Like there are multiple occurrences of the same record returned? Because the GROUP BY prevents that.

Comment: No, I was meant to say, when I edit program with id 2 its seprate entry is saving in another table, then I made another edit and another entry take place in database.
Then I make another edit for program id 3 so 2 3 4 or multiple unique entries having program id 3.
My goal is to show 2 records from Program table that these are program having id 2 and 3 whose edits are present in EditedProgram table so I just wants to order these 2 records whose id are 2 and 3 based on last inserted record in database.

Comment: So, if program id 3 has 4 edits and program id 2 has only 2 and latest edited entry is for id 2 so we will show program id 2 on the top of list to let admin know it is the program who has latest edits in the system. Thats my issue I am unable to sort these records.

You got?

Comment: Can you give an output about what you expect? In Markdown or CSV for instance (https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet#tables). Because it is kind of difficult to understand.

Comment: can we do chat here? thanks for your input again btw. So i can show you screenshots as well.

Comment: Sure, http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113453/room-for-basgys-and-learningror

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113455/discussion-between-basgys-and-learningror).

Comment: I am in chat now..